# Calculating exact change with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to solve an algorithm challenge over at FreeCodeCamp.

Here is the prompt for the problem:

> Design a cash register drawer function checkCashRegister() that accepts purchase price as the first argument (price), payment as the second argument (cash), and cash-in-drawer (cid) as the third argument.
>
> cid is a 2D array listing available currency.
>
> Return the string "Insufficient Funds" if cash-in-drawer is less than
>   the change due. Return the string "Closed" if cash-in-drawer is equal
>   to the change due.
>
> Otherwise, return change in coin and bills, sorted in highest to
>   lowest order.

My solution works for most of the parameters, except the following:

```
checkCashRegister(19.50, 20.00, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.10], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90.00], ["FIVE", 55.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["TWENTY", 60.00], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]])
```

should return: `[["QUARTER", 0.50]]`

```
checkCashRegister(3.26, 100.00, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.10], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90.00], ["FIVE", 55.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["TWENTY", 60.00], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]])
```

should return: `[["TWENTY", 60.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["FIVE", 15.00], ["ONE", 1.00], ["QUARTER", 0.50], ["DIME", 0.20], ["PENNY", 0.04]]`

```js
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  var change = 100 * (cash - price);
  var availableFunds = 0;

  var moneyValues = [1, 5, 10, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 10000];
  var amtToReturn = [];

  for (var i = cid.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    var amt = 0;
    while (moneyValues[i] <= change && cid[i][1] > 0 && change > 0){
      console.log("subtracting " + moneyValues[i]);
      cid[i][1] -= moneyValues[i]/100; // reduce amount in cid
      change -= moneyValues[i]; // reduce amount from change
      amt += moneyValues[i]/100; // keep track of how much money was taken out of cid
    }
    if (amt !== 0){
      // adds record of amount taken out of cid
      amtToReturn.push([cid[i][0], amt.toFixed(2)]);
    }
  }


  // if there is still some change left over
  if (change !== 0){
    console.log("broke");
    console.log(change);
    return "Insufficient Funds";
  }

  // if there is any money left in cid, it returns amtToReturn
  for (var j = 0; j < cid.length; j++){
    if (cid[j][1] > 0){
      console.log(amtToReturn);
      return amtToReturn;
    }
  }

  // if register is empty
  console.log("closed");
  return "Closed";

}

// Example cash-in-drawer array:
// [["PENNY", 1.01], 0
// ["NICKEL", 2.05], 1
// ["DIME", 3.10],   2
// ["QUARTER", 4.25],3
// ["ONE", 90.00],   4
// ["FIVE", 55.00],  5
// ["TEN", 20.00],   6
// ["TWENTY", 60.00],7
// ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]]8

checkCashRegister(19.50, 20.00, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.10], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90.00], ["FIVE", 55.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["TWENTY", 60.00], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]]);
```

I used the value of money in cents to avoid any floating point precision errors. I feel like there's just a tiny bug somewhere that is preventing me from finishing this problem.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/odyjcmfj/

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: Am I missing something? Your code returns exactly what you said you're expecting.

Comment: @Arnauld Apparently it does, but the page here wont seem to accept it: https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/exact-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're apparently expecting numbers as the second entry of the `["BILL", value]` arrays.

Just replace:

```
  amtToReturn.push([cid[i][0], amt.toFixed(2)]);
```

with:

```
  amtToReturn.push([cid[i][0], amt]);
```

and you should be all set to go.

Comment: Thank you so much!